# Read Log File for Monitoring using regex

Tags: powershell

I am trying to Monitor a Log file using Powershell, but I am not able to figure out what regex should I use to have my required Monitoring output.

```
Get-Content $file -wait | where {$_ -match "some regex"} | 
    foreach { send_email($_) }
```

Here is a sample of my Log File.

```
19:43:06.5230 Info {"message":"YourCode_Prod execution started","level":"Information","timeStamp":"2019-01-15T19:43:06.5132404+00:00","fingerprint":"588aeb19-76e5-415a-88ff-a69797eb414f","windowsIdentity":"AD\\gaurav.m","machineName":"EDEV-3","processName":"YourCode_Prod","processVersion":"1.0.6800.16654","fileName":"YourCode_Work","jobId":"22a537ae-35e6-4abd-a57d-9dd0c273e81a","robotName":"Gaurav"}
19:50:48.8014 Info {"message":"YourCode_Prod execution ended","level":"Information","timeStamp":"2019-01-15T19:50:48.8005228+00:00","fingerprint":"b12b7d6f-cf3a-4e24-b1e6-1cf4413c12e2","windowsIdentity":"AD\\gaurav.m","machineName":"EDEV-3","processName":"YourCode_Prod","processVersion":"1.0.6800.16654","fileName":"YourCode_Work","jobId":"22a537ae-35e6-4abd-a57d-9dd0c273e81a","robotName":"Gaurav","totalExecutionTimeInSeconds":462,"totalExecutionTime":"00:07:42"}
```

I tried to generate regex, but I could not find the right logic for this.

```
$searchpattern = [regex]"(?:(?:started))|(?:(?:ended))"
Get-Content -Path C:\Execution.log | foreach {
    if ($PSItem -match $searchpattern) {
        # does the entry have a valid date/time
        $time, $type, $data = $PSItem -split " ", 3
        $time
        $type
        $data
    }
}
```

I need to monitor this file which will have many lines, but I want to take action only for "execution started" and "execution ended".

I could separate the type of message time and the data. But I need to further drill down on the data.

This script will run every 5 min, so I will compare time -5 min and start reading log from there, as soon as I find ended or started I will take necessary action.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your log data is in JSON format, so you could simply process the extracted data as such.

```
Get-Content -Path C:\Execution.log | ForEach-Object {
    $time, $type, $json = $_ -split " ", 3
    $data = ConvertFrom-Json $json
    if ($data.message -match 'execution (started|ended)') {
        # do stuff
    }
}
```

Comment: I was close.. I did that now. Thanks.